# how to pass echo value in function in hidden type input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

In file `b.php` there is an echo value,i.e.`echo $abc;`and i want to pass this echo value in function in hidden type input so that this echo value goes to another page by function parameter which is called in input type hidden.
`<input type="hidden" name="" value="<?php fun( echo $abc;)?>">`

Comment: `<input type="hidden" name="" value="<?php echo fun( $abc);?>">` Just little change...... If your function `echos` the value at last then you will not need `echo` here else you will need

Comment: You wouldn't need the `echo` simply put something like `<input type="hidden" name="" value="<?php functionName($parameters) ?>"/>`

Comment: `echo` is only used to output string nothing else. It is not actually a function nor it returns any value. Refer [http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

Comment: but value of $abc is not transfered to another page where that function is defined.
function fun(stateId) {  
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById('citydiv').innerHTML=xhttp.responseText;
     
  }
  }       
   xhttp.open("GET","findcity.php?state="+stateId, true);
   xhttp.send();
  }

Comment: That's not a php function it is a js function. You can't call it with php

Comment: Then please give me the way to find it...

Comment: Are you trying to put result in value="" at page load or using ajax??

Comment: yes #garvit Ji. I want that Numeric Value of $abc is written then automatically that $abc value goes to fun() & then this value goes to previous page where this fun() is defined.

Comment: bhai jaldi se bta do...

Answer (score 0):

Just remove echo :

```
<input type="hidden" name="" value="<?php fun($abc) ?>">
```

Comment: but  value of $abc is not transfered to another page where that function is defiined.

Comment: function fun(stateId) {  
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
    document.getElementById('citydiv').innerHTML=xhttp.responseText;
     
  }
  }       
   xhttp.open("GET","findcity.php?state="+stateId, true);
   xhttp.send();
  }